# One to one relation between functions that coincide in certain values

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

I was reading a proof of multivariable calculus that suggested the following property might be true:

Given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$,  if $\forall x_1,x_2$  $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ $\iff$ $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$ then there exists a  one to one function $h(\cdot)$ on the range of $f(x)$ to the range of $g(x)$ such that $g(x)=h(f(x))$.

I have been trying to give a proof of the statement above but haven't been able to get anywhere. Is the statement true? If it is, can anyone give me a hint on how should $h(\cdot)$ be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be the range of $f$. Then $h\colon R\to S$ where $S$ is the range of $g$, with $h(y):=g(x)$, is well-defined by the properties of $f$ and $g$. Moreover $g(x)=h(f(x))$ for all $x$. $h$ is also one-to-one, since $h(u)=h(v)$ with, say $u=f(x), v=f(x')$ implies $h(u)=g(x), h(v)=g(x')$ and thus $g(x)=g(x')$ implying $f(x)=f(x')$, i.e., $u=v$.